# Convert or change date time to military time in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

1. In a Colab or Jupyter Python notebook
2. Trying to change datetime to military datetime
3. original: pickup_datetime = 02/10/2015 08:46:15 AM
4. error:    must be str, not Series (but unable to turn into string)
5. so,
6. separated datetime to: pickup_date 02/10/2015, pickup_time 08:46:15 AM
7. dateutil.parser.parsemust be str, not Series(x): from 02/10/2015 to: 2014/02/10
8. unable to convert or change time: 08:46:15 AM to 24 hour Military Time
9. error:  must be str, not Series (but unable to turn into string)
10. Help!

Code:

```
t = df['pickup_24'] 
datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M:%S %p')
# errors: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Code:

```
t = df['pickup_24']
datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M:%S %p')
# error:----> 4 datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%I:%M:%S %p')
# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Code:

```
df['pickup_24'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %p')
# error:strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

Comment: What do you mean for military time? For example, what do you expect from the time "08:46:15AM"? "084615"?

Comment: Can you please show the actual code you are using that generates these errors?

Comment: This is not a WordArt project. Please format your question properly.

Comment: Can you give the output when you do `print (t)` for the first code?

Comment: I miscoded the 't=' example. sorry, error is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` parameter and if necessary times add [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pickup_24':['08:46:15 AM','08:46:15 PM']})
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%I:%M:%S %p')
df['24H'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%I:%M:%S %p').dt.time
print (df)
     pickup_24               dates       24H     times
0  08:46:15 AM 1900-01-01 08:46:15  08:46:15  08:46:15
1  08:46:15 PM 1900-01-01 20:46:15  20:46:15  20:46:15
```

Or if inout data are datetimes add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pickup_24':['02/10/2015 08:46:15 AM','02/10/2015 08:46:15 PM']})
df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
df['strings'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                pickup_24           datetimes              strings
0  02/10/2015 08:46:15 AM 2015-02-10 08:46:15  02/10/2015 08:46:15
1  02/10/2015 08:46:15 PM 2015-02-10 20:46:15  02/10/2015 20:46:15
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael. your example worked "df['times'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_24'], format='%I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')"